# Can we get some input, please?

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking, story

The seven of us are pretty much surrounded.

Stevens thinks that the key is to keep together and everyone's on board with that. He's surely our most senior man, but I worry about him. He seems to get depressed a lot, but everyone does on occasion, right?. He watches the west, Dansforth at his side.

In the center of camp we have three inexperienced guys: Giano, Joplin, and Fenway. They look to our second-in-command, Harrison, for guidance.

My name is Kendricks. Although I'm pretty low on the totem pole, I've been studying the southeast and I think I've found a weakness, more or less.

Word spreads and the decision has been made: Tonight we make our move.

> What would you suggest as the most obvious, efficient order for us to take as we attempt an escape?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, considering that you're

> the center keys on the home row of a QWERTY keyboard (as explained by your initials, "input", "depressed a lot", and the stated locations)

I think it's reasonable that you would attempt an escape

> in the order `KJHGFDS`, since every other place is surrounded. As Bass noted, you may want to do a "commando attack" there, and then take an alternate route around the south. Just watch out for the lock (though I think any one of you should be able to deal with that) and any grave situations that may pop up just before you escape).

Comment: Adams, Quincy and Washington are blocking that route, maybe a commando attack in the reverse order would work better?

Comment: @Bass Ah, of course. An alternate route with more space, then another alternate route would help them shift their position. (I'd ask if they had any keys to handle the upcoming lock, but I think they can handle that just fine.) The only problem would be the possibility of a grave situation just before escaping.

Comment: @Bass: Like that?

Comment: @Chowzen Aaargh, almost woke up the kids in my fit of hysterical laughter, that picture's just so.. hilariously disturbing. (It's also a bit mean, but of course, mods are immune to that.) Now all that's missing is the green tick to signify that this was actually what you had planned all along. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would say in the order

> KJHGFDS

Since

> As @Deusovi stated, these are letters on a keyboard. The center keys are surrounded by other letters except in the southeast where there is the comma key. They should escape in order from closest to farthest from the comma key.